# how to version jax-ws web services

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

is there any best practice to version every release of my jax-ws based web services build ? I have seen a few ways to version REST based services (for example to include the version information in URL etc.) Is there any other different way of versioning JAX-WS based web services. .

Answer (score 0):

To version my services, I use a different targetNamespace.

For instance, I add the annotation to my interface :

@WebService(name = "YourService", targetNamespace = "http://whatever/you/want/VersionNumber")

Running wsgen you will end up with a different targetNamespace in you xsd. All old clients won't be able to use your webservice, with a clean, "fail fast" error.

However, as this is quite annoying, I only update this version when the signature of the service has changed, to prevent from wierd, hard to debug, errors